# Import fixed width UTF-8 file into SQL 2008R2, variabel file names

Tags: sql, utf-8, import, width, fixed

I have to import text files with different names (like the following) into SQL Server 2008.

1. XYZ0000746263.txt
2. XYZ0000746269.txt
3. XYZ0000745860.txt

The filename always starts with XYZ, and the number is always higher than the file before.

The format of the file is fixed-width, with UTF-8 encoding.

```
SHINST 1020130613    
SHINSD0745860182650  940PI67100000           dataw11     2012CH 01002601900100 848CRU        
SHINSD0745860182650  940PI67066900           dataa12     9434CH 00701801400030 848CRU         
SHINSD0745860182650  940PI67160300          adsfaf13     1205CH 04203601000160 848CRU     
SHINSD0745860182650  940PI67171300           data 14     1205CH 01803501200120 848ND1  
SHINSD0745860182650  940PI67079000           asdfs15     8400CH 00702601400040 848ND1    
SHINSD0745860182620  940PI67053900           data 16     6877CH 01904101100130 848ND1    
SHINSD0745860182620  940PI67156100          text  17     3003CH 08906202902460 848ND2    
SHINSD0745860182650  940PI67110700         alskdjf18     1000CH 02603900900130 848ND2    
SHINSD0745860182620  940PI67123900       asfasdffa19     8048CH 01502300900020 848ND2    
SHINSD0745860182650  940PI67066300           data 20     8952CH 01002601900090 848ND2    
SHINSF000012
```

The first line contains `SHINST`, then the number of records in the file, then a date in the format `YYYYMMDD`.

The records contain `SHINSD`, then a 13-digit number, then the fixed-width records.

The last line contains `SHINSF`, then a six-digit number with the total number of lines of the file.

I want to automatically import files in this format into an SQL table. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
BULK INSERT tablename FROM 'c:\File.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ' ')
```

If the ' '(space) is your field delimiter.
Of course table table name columns must be the same as in file (count and length). 
You can make a procedure and give it a filenamepath only, as in these [exaples](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-bulk-insert-to-load-a-text-file)

The only problem is first and last row in file, cause they are different and I don;t know if you need to insert the mas well. If you need to ignore them, maybe you'll need a script to eliminate them.

Comment: I need the date out of the first line on every data record line, to know when the data record was sent to me. The record set is build up with fixed width data, I could show it on the correct way in this post.

Comment: Well that could be done with bash script, to prepare files for `BULK INSERT`, but if you want to do it all in `SQL`, than I sugest you make a procedure and dump file in #temptable(tempfield(nvarchar(max))) in it. Than you can do various string manipulations, like `select top 1` and substing to get that date into variable, than prepare inserts with the rest of the fields  and add your time stamp on the field you want...

Comment: maybe you have a example for me, because I'm a beginner ... :-)